# Pyxero invoice filter doesn't work

Tags: python, api, get

I'm using [Pyxero](https://github.com/freakboy3742/pyxero) to download some invoices, but the following code pulls out invoices from before the datetime:

```
import Xero
ckey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#link to private RSA key
with open('privatekey.pem') as keyfile:
    rsa_key = keyfile.read()

credentials = PrivateCredentials(ckey, rsa_key)
xero = Xero(credentials)

invoices = xero.invoices.filter(since=datetime.datetime(2015,4,1))
```

Has anyone used the Pyxero invoice filter successfully in a get request? Our company has too many invoices and doing a get request with no filter causes a `Segmentation Fault`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That filter is returning all invoices last modified since the specified date (it uses the If-Modified-Since HTTP header). I have tested your code and it works for me, so perhaps you might be filtering on the wrong date field?